# Run Script on Browsers Different Than IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I want to run a specific jQuery/JS code on any browser but IE.

Currently I am using this, but it does not work in Chrome:

```
    <!--[if !IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert("non ie");
            $("#login_userid").focus();
        });
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

The alert nor the focus part is executed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is better to do feature detection than browser sniffing. Check out Modernizer http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you need

```
<![if ! IE]>

<![endif]>
```